# Using JSONPath to extract variable or key name

Tags: json, xpath, jsonpath

I have a JSON string that's of the format:

```
[{"topic":0},{"topic2":2}]
```

Using jsonpath expression like:

```
$.*
```

I can extract the values, ie, 0, 2 - but I cant' find any way of getting the variable name to the left of the ':' - is this possible using JsonPath?

For example, I would want an expression that would give me:  "topic", "topic2", (etc) (variable number of name/value pairs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know it's impossible.

Comment: you were correct, @Dmytro - I had to change the format of the json - it was wrong.